# The best way to see an exception stack trace in Android Studio on application crash if the exception was thrown in coroutine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When my app crashes in ordinary code, I can open the "run" tab in Android Studio and see exactly why my app crashed. But if the exception that crashed my app was thrown in coroutine I don't see anything on the tab. Is it alright or am I missing something in my project\Android Studio configuration?

The only place, where I can see the exception stack trace is the "View Summary" link on my phone in an application crash dialog.

Logcat shows TaskCancelledException with nothing in particular, and only if I remove "Show only selected application" filter.

I have found the solution, but I doubt whether or not it's the most efficient and idiomatic way to do so. Here's the code

```
// Storebase.kt
@Suppress("unused")
abstract class StoreBase(private val thisLifecycle: Lifecycle, private val context: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO): CoroutineScope, LifecycleObserver, LifecycleOwner {

    init {
        @Suppress("LeakingThis")
        thisLifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    private val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        Log.e("ERROR", "Coroutine has thrown an exception")
        Exception(throwable).printStackTrace()
        throw throwable
    }

    private val compositeJob = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = context + compositeJob + handler

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        compositeJob.cancel()
        thisLifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return thisLifecycle
    }
}
```

My gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=on
```

Comment: does anything appears in logcat tab ?

Comment: @VivekMishra nice question. Added the information about logcat to my post

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/exception-handling.md#exception-handling

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, I'll read that properly, thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that a resumed coroutine's stack trace is nothing like the original one before the first suspension. It's for the most part worthless, you get the inverted trace of those functions that have returned after resuming, and no info on their calling functions.